# Requesting URL parameters in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, request

The way I use to request parameters from URL is

if URL is- `http://www.domain.ext/default.aspx?id=123&name=abc`

In the above example we can request two parameter i.e. `id` and `name` from page `default.aspx` as `string myid = Request["id"];` and `string myname = Request["name"];`

But in Facebook profile's URL it shows something of this kind.

`http://www.facebook.com/john.deo` or `http://www.facebook.com/madcoder`

Where there wont be any page name and to define name with syntax. How to request the parameters (john.deo or madcoder) from URL in C#?

Comment: That's not really a parameter - it's part of the URL. I think you'll have to parse it out of the URL yourself. You may be able to submit the URL part to the graph API and get the user ID back instead if that's what you actually need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding rules to an htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?name=$1
```

This rule will mean that if you type into the browser http://www.mydomain.co.uk/john you can get the value 'john' by requesting the 'name' parameter.

Comment: Great! But I guess htaccess is for Apache servers right? I am working on IIS.

Comment: Take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Those are not URL parameters, those are used to identify a resource.
You could use regex you're only objective is to get the "john.deo" in the given url

Comment: Can you please provide me with any sample code to do that using regex?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how complex your solution is. But one easy way to do this is by using page routing.

You could register a route in your `Global.asax -> Application_Start` like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route name", "requestformat", "physicalfile", checkPhysicalUrlAccess, routeValueDefaults, routeConstraints);
```

Then in your request format specify parameters like "{name}" and then default the name parameter in the ´routeValueDefaults´ dictionary and put a contstraint on it in the ´routeContstrains´ dictionary. The constraint can be specified by a reqular expression, so if you want the names to be all only characters you could use something like this "\w+".

The parameter then end up in the `Page.RouteData["name"]` collection of the physical page.